# C Program..help

Tags: c

> c:\users\yan\desktop\glossary_demo.h(2)
>   : error C2236: unexpected 'class'
>   'defined'
>   c:\users\yan\desktop\glossary_demo.h(2)
>   : error C2144: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before type 'defined'
>   c:\users\yan\desktop\glossary_demo.h(2)
>   : error C2501: 'abstract' : missing
>   storage-class or type specifiers
>   c:\users\yan\desktop\glossary_demo.h(2)
>   : fatal error C1004: unexpected end of
>   file found Error executing cl.exe.

```
#include < stido.h>
#include < string.h>
#include < stdlib.h>

char*ArryString[1000];

char*key[80];

char result[256];

int IineRend;


#include"glossary_demo.h"//not implemented.use glossary_stored at the main time

int main()
{



  IineRend=rendFile();
  //sortArray();

for(int i=0; i<IineRend;i++)
{
printf("%S\n",ArryString[i]);
}
while(inputkey()!=0)
}

int value;

bool found =searchkey(&value);
displayResult(found,value);

}
```

**I make a new file(h) on the Desktop>>>>>>glossary_demo.h**

**the following content:**

abstract class

a class defined to make creating subclass easier

array

an ordered collection of values

collection

class that used for grouping and manipulating related objects

compile time

the time during which the source code is analyzed and converted into object code

dictionary

a collection of key/value pairs

framework

a collection of classes, functions and protocols that are related to support certain

platform

instance

a concrete representation of a class

message

the method and its associated arguments that are sent to an object

retain count

a count of the number of times an object is referenced

selector

the name used to select the method to execute for an object

---

***I want to the screen showing ,when I input:selector then show me( the name used.......***

Answer (score 2):

You're using

```
#include "glossary_demo.h"
```

which is basically injecting the contents of `glossary_demo.h` into your code at compile-time. Your `glossary_demo.h` file isn't valid C, which is why you're getting all those errors.

It sounds like *really* you want to load a text file at execution time, which is very different.

Comment: so what can i do ? i just want to when i input array or arrays can display (an ordered collection of values) this sentence....

Comment: @pepajen: No, you need to rethink this from the start. Given that this is homework, I think it's best if you talk it through with your teacher - my gut feeling is that you have enough of a misunderstanding to make it inappropriate to try to fix on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged your question `C`, but `class` can be used only in `C++`, not `C`.

Your error is from file `glossary_demo.h`, please show contents of that.

BTW, it must be

```
#include <stdio.h> (not <stido.h>)
```